# PHP Session is NULL when going back to main index.php page

Tags: php, sql, authentication, web, session

```
<?php
    #this is dbconfig.php : assume all connection values are correct

    session_start();
    $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $host = "mysql.example.com"; /* Host name */
    $user = "XXXX"; /* User */
    $pass = "XXXX"; /* Password */
    $dbname = "XXXX"; /* Database name */
    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);

?>
```

```
<?php
# THIS IS THE MAIN MENU (HOME PAGE) 
# THIS PAGE FAILS TO GET SESSION WHEN MOVING TO HERE FROM THE PROFILE PAGE VIA BUTTON

  include 'dbconfig.php';
  
  var_dump($_SESSION);  # returns NULL, should return same as profile
  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $username = $_SESSION["username"];
    $password = $_SESSION["password"];
    header('Location: https://example.com/profile');
  }
?>
```

```
<?php
# THIS IS THE USERS PROFILE PAGE

include 'dbconfig.php';
var_dump($_SESSION); # This gives CORRECT data and verifies the session is set 

$username; $password;
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
  $username = $_SESSION["username"];
  $password = $_SESSION["password"];

} else {
  header("Location:https://example.com");
  exit();
}
?>

<button><a href="https://example.com/api/logout.php">Logout</a></button>
<button><a href="https://example.com">Home</a></button> 
# WHEN PRESSING THIS BUTTON IT TAKES YOU TO HOME PAGE  
# (ABOVE) EXCEPT IT DOESNT HAVE A SESSION ON THE HOME PAGE FOR SOME REASON
```

My question is why am I losing the session when I go from Profile page to Home page (no session on home page, I'm confused here.
Thank you!

I tried changing all links to match my host, EX : [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to example.com (correct)
I tried adding `session_start();` to all pages
I made sure all files were updated to SFTP correctly

Still I can't get the Home page to keep the session when the user returns to it from their profile page.
when I `var_dump($_SESSION)` on home page I get NULL

Comment: Assuming you are using a browser as the frontend, use inspect and keep network tab open. See what's the request going out. For example, in Chrome, under network, select home page on left panel, and under "cookies" , see if "request cookies" are being sent on the home page. Compare this with other pages. My guess... request cookies are not sent. If so, use phpinfo() to see session parameters and cookie parameters and change them appropriately.

Comment: Also, if you can, share what are the cookie parameters that you see in the inspect tool: same site, httponly, etc. etc. It seems you are using cookies for session. Please confirm.

Comment: So where are you actually _populating_ the session with data?

Comment: _"I tried changing all links to match my host"_ - why are you using absolute URLs in your links to begin with, and not relative ones?

Comment: I had (perhaps incorrectly) assumed that the session data was being populated in a different file that wasn't shared yet, as he says it is working on some pages.